# when i run the program it throws error and in vs code it is giving "error:location.condition is not callable"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, weather-api, assistant

I am trying to build an assistant using python. And it keep showing the error
"location.condition is not callable pylint(not-callable)" & "location.forecast is not callable pylint(not-callable)"

```
    elif 'current weather in' in command:   
        reg_ex = re.search('current weather in (.*)', command)
        if reg_ex:
            city = reg_ex.group(1)
            weather = Weather(unit=Unit.CELSIUS)
            location = weather.lookup_by_location(city)
            condition = location.condition()
            TalkToMe('The Current weather in %s is %s.' 
            'The tempeture is %d.1 C degree' %(city, condition.text(), 
               (int(condition.temp))))

    elif 'weather forecast in' in command:
        reg_ex = re.search('weather forecast in (.*)', command)
        if reg_ex:
            city = reg_ex.group(1)
            weather = Weather()
            location = weather.lookup_by_location(city)
            forecasts = location.forecast()
            for i in range(0,3):
                TalkToMe("On %s will it %s."
                'The maximum temperture will be %d.1 C degree.'
                'The lowest temperature will be %d.1 C degrees.' % (forecasts[i].date(), forecasts[i].text(), (int(forecasts[i].high)), (int(forecasts[i].low))))
```

It should tell the weather condition or the weather forecast

Comment: `condition` is an attribute not a method. Try `location.condition` instead of `location.condition()`. Same for the forecast. Also, no need to yell with all caps.

Comment: @glhr, indeed, I've edited the caps in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example at https://pypi.org/project/weather-api/ shows:

```
weather = Weather(unit=Unit.CELSIUS)
location = weather.lookup_by_location('dublin')
condition = location.condition
print(condition.text)
```

However, you are doing `lookup.condition()`. The parentheses cause Python to "call" `lookup.condition`, i.e. requiring it to be callable.

Note that pylint is a static code analyzer. It tries to warn you in advance for problems in your code, so you can fix them before actually running the program. A static code analyzer is not always correct, but in this case it seems to be. Removing the parentheses should solve the problem.